# PodioForbiddenError: "The app with id 123 does not have the right delete on item with id 12345"

Tags: php, podio

The item to be deleted via API is in the corresponding app 123.
It is being created from a user via the reference field of another app.

```
PodioItem::delete($item_id);
```

It actually used to work until a few hours ago.
So I assume while playing with the API I must have changed something on the rights. Because now API throws

> PodioForbiddenError: "The app with id 123 does not have the right delete on item with id 12345"

I knew that regular users (and below) are restricted when it comes to deleting items not being created by themselves.

What are the parameters / triggers that will change the apps right to (not) be able delete an item and how can I revert them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by authenticating as a user (admin rights).

Proposal to extend the error reporting with

> this item is not owned by this app